# Update moderator election post comment notification link

Tags: feature-request, bug, notifications, election, global-inbox

Ever since the Primary voting started, the inbox notification links for comments on nominations is broken.

Clicking on the notification used to take you directly to the candidates nomination post with the comments enabled, but it now defaults to the candidates post in the primary tab, without comments enabled. You now have to manually go to the nomination tab and then scroll down to the post. It seems this problem was [there in previous elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112133/187954) too.

Could the link be updated to be in the format of:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=nomination#<post_id>
```

instead of

```
http://stackoverflow.com/election/4?<post_id>
```